# Unity3d - Cast dynamic shadows without processing multiple lights

Tags: unity, performance, lighting, shadows

**Back Story**

I've built a game with a friend and all goes well until there are too many spheres under a group of 5 lights, then things start getting choppy.

**Troubleshooting**

I've found that by turning off all of these lights but one the game runs smoothly, the problem is that the shadows are not realistic at all. Because of the 4 main lights, the objects should have four main shadows.

**My Ideas**

I wanted to use a "projector" but that is too static for multiple & random appearing / disappearing objects. I might be able to do a projector per sphere  but I'm hoping there is an easier way as this would require a lot of work to get just right.

**Question**

How can I get 4 lights to cast a raycast shadow on a group of dynamically moving spheres (100 of them) without processing the light portion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got rid of the four extra lights and instead attached projectors to the items. The projectors shoot black, circular png shapes onto the ground. It took a bit to soften up the shadows / lock rotation etc but it came out nicely and we saved the performance that we needed to.